# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration:0x000000033fedc0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am new to Ruby on rails, I am doing a facebook and google authentication using omni_auth and stuck in this!

When I run rake db:migrate, show the following error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration:0x000000033fedc0>
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:664:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:416:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/rails_project/Devise-Omniauth/db/migrate/20180129115427_update_users.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `load_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:773:in `migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1051:in `use_transaction?'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:961:in `rescue in block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:958:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

This is causing due to this file:

```
class UpdateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column(:users, :provider, :string, limit: 50, null: false, default: '')
    add_column(:users, :uid, :string, limit: 500, null: false, default: '')
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you using rails 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using rails 4.2.

and versioned migration worked in rails 5 only

just remove `[5.0]` from your migration and it will work fine.

like:

```
class UpdateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column(:users, :provider, :string, limit: 50, null: false, default: '')
    add_column(:users, :uid, :string, limit: 500, null: false, default: '')
  end
end
```