# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I started to get this error:

"Your RubyGems version (2.5.2.3) has a bug that prevents `required_ruby_version` from working for Bundler. Any scripts that use `gem install bundler` will break as soon as Bundler drops support for your Ruby version. Please upgrade RubyGems to avoid future breakage and silence this warning by running `gem update --system 3.2.3`"

so I upgraded to:

```
[root@jobs ~]# gem --version
2.7.10
```

and now I am getting this:

```
    fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cd /home/migrations/pure-migrations/purelive && bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development", "delta": "0:00:01.518654", "end": "2022-07-11 09:31:16.503200", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2022-07-11 09:31:14.984546", "stderr": "rake aborted!\n
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration:0x000000000363e040>\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:661:in `block in method_missing'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:417:in `method_missing'\n
/home/migrations/pure-migrations/purelive/db/migrate/20220624091337_php2054_drop_dynmark_impersonation.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:774:in `load_migration'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:770:in `migration'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `disable_ddl_transaction'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1048:in `use_transaction?'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:958:in `rescue in block in migrate'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `block in migrate'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'\n
/home/migrations/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'\n
/home/migrations/bin/bundle:30:in `block in <main>'\n
/home/migrations/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'\n
```

In migration.rb I have:

```
416      def method_missing(name, *args, &block) # :nodoc:
417        (delegate || superclass.delegate).send(name, *args, &block)
418      end

629    def say_with_time(message)
630      say(message)
631      result = nil
632      time = Benchmark.measure { result = yield }
633      say "%.4fs" % time.real, :subitem
634      say("#{result} rows", :subitem) if result.is_a?(Integer)
635      result
636    end

649    def method_missing(method, *arguments, &block)
650      arg_list = arguments.map{ |a| a.inspect } * ', '
651
652      say_with_time "#{method}(#{arg_list})" do
653        unless @connection.respond_to? :revert
654          unless arguments.empty? || [:execute, :enable_extension, :disable_extension].include?(method)
655            arguments[0] = proper_table_name(arguments.first, table_name_options)
656            if [:rename_table, :add_foreign_key].include?(method)
657              arguments[1] = proper_table_name(arguments.second, table_name_options)
658            end
659          end
660        end
661        return super unless connection.respond_to?(method)
662        connection.send(method, *arguments, &block)
663      end
664    end
```

On this server I have this installed:

```
[root@jobs ~]# gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.2.6)
actionpack (4.2.6)
actionview (4.2.6)
active_record_migrations (4.2.6.1)
activejob (4.2.6)
activemodel (4.2.6)
activerecord (4.2.6)
activesupport (4.2.6)
arel (6.0.4)
bigdecimal (1.2.8)
builder (3.2.4)
bundler (default: 1.16.6)
composite_primary_keys (8.0.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.1.10)
crass (1.0.6)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
globalid (0.4.2)
i18n (0.9.5)
io-console (0.4.5)
jmespath (1.6.1)
json (1.8.6, 1.8.3.1)
loofah (2.18.0)
mail (2.7.1)
mini_mime (1.1.2)
mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
minitest (5.15.0)
mysql2 (0.3.17)
nokogiri (1.10.10)
psych (2.1.0.1)
rack (1.6.13)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.6)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.4)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.9)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.3)
railties (4.2.6)
rake (13.0.6)
rdoc (4.2.1)
rubygems-update (2.7.10)
seedbank (0.5.0)
sprockets (3.0.0)
sprockets-rails (3.2.2)
thor (1.2.1)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
tzinfo (1.2.9)
```

I am presuming that there is a version mismatch with rails or something else but I don't know which one to test, how can I fix it?

Later edit:

```
cat 20220624091337_php2054_drop_dynmark_impersonation.rb
class Php2054DropDynmarkImpersonation < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  def up
    execute "DELETE FROM pool_preference WHERE preference_id = '66';"
    execute "DELETE FROM preference WHERE preference_name = 'dynmarkImpersonationUserName';"
  end

  def down
    execute "INSERT INTO preference (preference_id, preference_type, preference_name, permission, allowed_levels) VALUES('66', 'smsGateway', 'dynmarkImpersonationUserName', 'readonly', 'group');"
  end
end
```

Solution was to remove the [4.2] from the above:

Later edit:

```
cat 20220624091337_php2054_drop_dynmark_impersonation.rb
class Php2054DropDynmarkImpersonation < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "DELETE FROM pool_preference WHERE preference_id = '66';"
    execute "DELETE FROM preference WHERE preference_name = 'dynmarkImpersonationUserName';"
  end

  def down
    execute "INSERT INTO preference (preference_id, preference_type, preference_name, permission, allowed_levels) VALUES('66', 'smsGateway', 'dynmarkImpersonationUserName', 'readonly', 'group');"
  end
end
```

Comment: What is in /home/migrations/pure-migrations/purelive/db/migrate/20220624091337_php2054_drop_dynmark_impersonation.rb  (when seeing ruby stack traces always first focus on files that you created yourself first

Comment: cat 20220624091337_php2054_drop_dynmark_impersonation.rb
class Php2054DropDynmarkImpersonation < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  def up
    execute "DELETE FROM pool_preference WHERE preference_id = '66';"
    execute "DELETE FROM preference WHERE preference_name = 'dynmarkImpersonationUserName';"
  end

  def down
    execute "INSERT INTO preference (preference_id, preference_type, preference_name, permission, allowed_levels) VALUES('66', 'smsGateway', 'dynmarkImpersonationUserName', 'readonly', 'group');"
  end
end

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501595/nomethoderror-undefined-method-for-activerecordmigration0x000000033fe/48501837#48501837

Comment: I removed the [4.2] and it worked fine. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Like the answer says. You are using Rails 4, but versioned migrations are not supported until Rails 5.